# Heat Equation at interface of 2 materials using Finite Difference Method - Can it be non-dimensional?

Tags: thermodynamics, computational-physics, diffusion

I looked at a [similar question](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/107761/how-to-solve-the-heat-equation-for-compound-materials-with-different-heat-conduc) to find out how to discretize the heat equation in 2 spacial dimensions at the boundary between two materials. I am required to use explicit method (forward-time-centered-space) to solve. I believe I have arrived at a reasonable approximation with the following:

\begin{align}\frac{T^{k+1}_{i,j}-T^k_{i,j}}{\Delta t}&=\frac1{h^2}\left[\left(\alpha^k_{i+\frac12,j}-\alpha^k_{i-\frac12,j}\right)\left(T^k_{i+\frac12,j}-T^k_{i-\frac12,j}\right)+\left(\alpha^k_{i,j+\frac12}-\alpha^k_{i,j-\frac12}\right)\left(T^k_{i,j+\frac12}-T^k_{i,j-\frac12}\right)\right.\\
&\quad\left.+\alpha^k_{i,j}\left(T^k_{i-1,j}-2T^k_{i,j}+T^k_{i+1,j}\right)+\alpha^k_{i,j}\left(T^k_{i,j-1}-2T^k_{i,j}+T^k_{i,j+1}\right)\right]
\end{align}

where any index $\pm\frac12$ represents the average of the value at current index and the one right in front of or behind,  i.e.:
$$\frac12(T_{i\pm1}+T_{i}).$$

$k$ is the time index, $i,j$ are the spacial indices, $h$ is a grid size, and $\Delta t$ is a time step.

This was determined through the generalized heat equation in $x$ and $y$ dimensions $$\frac{\partial T}{\partial t}=\nabla\cdot\left(\alpha\nabla T\right).$$

I have two questions:

1. Is the discretized form of the heat equation above correct? If not, how do I fix it?
2. Is it possible to use a nondimensional time step $\tau = \frac{\alpha\Delta t}{h^2}$ for this problem even though the $\alpha$ is changing across materials? If the nondimensional time step is changing, how would I then extract the actual solution in space and time after it is finished solving?

Comment: For #2, I'd suspect that you'd use the maximum, as it's done in the CFL condition.

Comment: Should I then use a constant time step $\tau$ ? And then scale it by whichever $\alpha$ range I'm in?

Comment: At the discontinuity between the materials, you have $$k_1\left(\frac{\partial T}{\partial x}\right)_1=k_2\left(\frac{\partial T}{\partial x}\right)_2$$where k is the thermal conductivity, and the subscripts refer to the two sides of the interface.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I discuss in that answer that the FDM for the 1D diffusion equation with variable coefficient ends up being,
$$
\frac{T^{n+1}_i-T^n_i}{dt}=\frac{1}{dx^2}\left[\alpha_{i+\frac{1}{2}}\left(T^n_{i+1}-T^n_{i}\right)-\alpha_{i-\frac{1}{2}}\left(T^n_i-T^n_{i-1}\right)\right]
$$
with $\alpha_{i+\frac12}=\left(\alpha_{i+1}+\alpha_{i}\right)/2$. Extending this 2D should be direct: just add $j$ subscript to all terms, then add a similar $\left[\cdots\right]/dy^2$ term. So it seems you've got a few extra terms, at least at an initial, cursory look. I also discuss the Crank-Nicolson version [in this answer](https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/137707/25301).

For the timestep, $dt$, you need to satisfy the [Courant-Freidrich-Lewy condition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Courant%E2%80%93Friedrichs%E2%80%93Lewy_condition) (CFL) for diffusion equations:
$$
CFL\leq\max\left(\alpha\right)\cdot\frac{dt}{\left(dx^2+dy^2\right)}
$$
where, typically, $CFL=1/2$. So there will be one time step and its value depends on only the *maximum* value of the (variable) diffusion coefficient.